# Is it possible to build a stateless Node REST API as a producer for Kafka?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

We internally use NodeJS for stateless REST APIs. This lets us scale horizontally when we need to. We're currently looking into using Kafka for various streaming tasks, but we'd like to continue exposing REST APIs off of stateless services.

We'd initially assumed each replica will be a producer, problem solved. However, it seems as if Kafka producers can't be stateless, as otherwise we start losing things like sequence. Which may or may not be a major problem for us depending on our use case.

I've taken a look at the Confluent REST Proxy, but that seems to rely on the Confluent Platform, which has other problems for us.

Two questions:

1. Is there an implementation where we can build a stateless multi-replica node service that acts as a single producer?
2. If we were to have a producer per REST service replica, is sequencing (like race events) the only problem we'll have?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The rest proxy is a standalone service and can be added to any Kafka cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can use producer per REST service replica. Only thing you need to consider is `partitioning`

- make sure all producer use same partitioner mechanism. Then same entity with same key, (you can configure partitioner function to use any value in message to decide the partition) will go to same partition. Then all events with same entity will add to same partition and make sure the sequence processes.

Comment: How about the race event scenario where 2 queries come in one after another (A then B), but due to a delay in A, B arrives first. Even if they are both sent to the same partition, the sequence would now be B then A wouldn't it, and thus the sequence would now be out of sync?

Comment: Yes, Network delays can break sequence in anywhere.

Comment: @Jty Not all applications require absolute order, so there's no general solution to that problem other than only allowing one producer to be active at any time via distributed locks